# How can I bypass android 9 VPN with iptables?

Tags: networking, 9.0-pie, iptables

I'm targeting specific app with UID rule `-m owner --uid-owner 1337` and I want this app always bypass VPN and use direct Wi-fi/Mobile Data connection. Ideally, I also want it to be universal, if possible, because I might switch the VPN app I use (currently have two) and I dont want to rewrite the rule and re-target new interface for it.

What are my options? I can provide output of `ifconfig`, whatever, but it kinda defeats aforementioned point 2).

P.S. I know that majority of VPN apps have exclusion list but because I already use AFWall+ I dont want to use that list and mess with iptables even more, polluting it with weird routes combnations.